# Creating a windows service that downloads files from azure every hour

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-services, download

What's the best way to get this to work?

I've tried some stuff but the AzureService didn't want to work with the service. The service on its own worked and so did the AzureService, but together didn't work.

Is there anyone whose already done something like this?

I put the service on Local System but I was never able to get the service to run as it wouldn't compile with the AzureService, it gave a reference error yet there was a reference, I was unable to remove this issue.

The need for a service is that files need to be updated without user interaction.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. For example, under which credentials is your service running? By default, services run under SYSTEM, which can't establish network connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly given the enhancements made by Scott Gu's team recently, I would think a simple scheduled powershell script would be easiest. Here's [Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WindowsAzureNoKidding.aspx) take on the topic.

Also - the [at command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) and [running a powershell script from command line](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/05/05/running-powershell-scripts-from-cmd-exe/).